# Oracle 12c save state works only in open mode

Tags: oracle, savestate, oracle12c

Hi DBA's,

I have a query. I am using below query to save the state of PDB's but it works only when CDB is in open state but fails in case of open read only. Even in case of open ready only the PDB's might be in read only or mounted state. Is there any work around or am i missing something?

"ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL SAVE STATE"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container has to be open for write otherwise the save state cannot be "saved" within the containers meta data.

also, can only save the state of READ ONLY or READ WRITE (not MOUNTED) pluggable databases.

finally, this function is only available in 12.1.0.2 (not 12.1.0.1)

hope this helps

Dave

Comment: That means it if CDB is read only then after restart all PDB's goes back to mounted state? Isn't it a gap?

Comment: they will go back to a mounted state unless they had a different  state saved previously before setting the CDB to READ ONLY. 

If you want the CDB to be read only and the PDBs to restart automatically, i would set the CDB to READ WRITE, open the PDBs and save their state, then close the CDB and open as READ ONLY.

Comment: How about active data guard configuration? We can never save state? Is there any special handling for that?

Comment: sorry can't help with that, haven't used data guard. What it wrong with my suggestion from before? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to take the offline backup of ADG. Before going offline i have to save the state and get the PDB's back to the original state. I could write script to automate for online databases but since ADG is in open read only there is no way to record state hence the issue.

Comment: the only options i can see are either to write a script (as you suggest) or use my option of open in READ WRITE, save the state and then open again READ ONLY. As you are shutting down anyway i don't see a problem with this solution.